# Meteor Publish Returning Empty Cursor

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, meteor

I'm using Backbone.js to route profile views so I can view data belonging to /user, and that part works fine. I'm able to generate an _id based on the username and pass it into the server publish function, which logs it. However, when I log the results back to the client in the subscribe function, my result looks like this:

Object {stop: function, ready: function}

```
//Client Side
Template.userquery.userproject = function() {
    var query = Session.get('userquery');
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username: query});
    if (user) {
        console.log(user._id); //(works)
        campaigns = Meteor.subscribe('userquery', user._id, function() {
            console.log('ready'); //(works)
        });
        console.log(campaigns); //(returns Object {stop: function, ready: function})
        return campaigns;
    }
}
//Server Side
Meteor.publish('userquery', function(userid) {
    console.log('break');
    console.log(userid); //(I get userid in Terminal)
    var campaigns = Campaigns.find({owner: userid}, {fields: {owner: 1, name: 1}});
    if (campaigns) {
        console.log(campaigns);
        return campaigns;
    }
});
```

Am I missing something in this function? I have autopublish turned off because it was generating my search twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meteor.subscribe`, [according to the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe), "Returns a handle that provides stop() and ready() methods." So the behaviour you're seeing is intended.

Comment: Publish doesn't return a cursor, it gives you a handle which you can use to stop or restart the subscription. To use the data just call your `Campaigns.find` as normal, as long as its after the subscription is complete, where you say 'ready' (timewise not codewise)